# Replace multiline text wtih sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to replace a multi-line text which contains XML in all files named pom.xml.
In practice, I need to replace this section:

```
<groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
<artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
```

with:

```
<groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
<artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
```

I've come up with the following sed:

```
find . -name pom.xml -exec sed -i 's/\<groupId\>javax\.enterprise\<\/groupId\>
      \<artifactId\>cdi-api\<\/artifactId\>/\<groupId\>jakarta\.enterprise\<\/groupId\>
        \<artifactId\>jakarta\.enterprise\.cdi-api\<\/artifactId\>/g' {} +
```

However, from the output it's returned "command not terminated".
I'm  not too familiar with multiline replacement, could you suggest any fix or other tool to do it?
Thanks

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Besides what @Cyrus said, instead of using literal newlines you should have used `\n` and specified `-z` for `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

First test without `-i` in a folder with one file.
Newer versions of GNU `sed` support the option `-z`.

```
find . -name pom.xml -exec \
   sed -rz 's#(<groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>\n<artifactId>)(cdi-api</artifactId>)#\1jakarta.enterprise.\2#g' {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it but it didn't have any effect on the file. I was trying with an online exp parser but it fails to capture text which is after the first line (`<groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>`) even through I have used "\r" to separate lines

Comment: When you have a windows environment, you might have `\r\n`, so try to replace the string with `...</groupId>\r\n<artifactId>...`